# Scene2D fadeIn fadeOut breaks when using shaders

Tags: libgdx, fragment-shader, scene2d

I'm using a simple shader to do a vignette transition effect in my game on each screen load (picked up from this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/libgdx-cross-platform-game-development-cookbook)). I use this transition effect in my menu screens. All is well with the exception that my fadeIn , fadeOut animations that I apply to the buttons of the menu don't have any effect with this added shader; in fact no alpha value has any effect  on any actor on the screen when I use this shader.

Here's the vertex shader:

```
...
gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
v_color = a_color;
```

And the fragment shader:

```
...
vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
...
gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.r, texColor.g, texColor.b, texColor.a);
```

How can I fix the alpha issue so actors render the alpha properly with the shader ?

Maybe the fragment blow will work? But how do I set the alpha for every actor of the screen?

```
uniform float ALPHA;
...
gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.r, texColor.g, texColor.b, texColor.a * ALPHA);
```

Comment: Replace `ALPHA` with `v_color.a` on your last line and you should be good. You'll need to declare v_color in your fragment shader like it is in the vertex shader.

Comment: Hey , thanks it worked perfectly ! I'd be glad to accept your answer, please add it as the solution :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fade animations utilize the alpha of the vertex color. This is passed into SpriteBatch which passes it to the vertex shader as `a_color`. Your vertex shader already passes the color to the fragment shader as `v_color`, so in your fragment shader, you need to multiply the final alpha by this fade value:

Fragment shader:

```
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
//...
gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.r, texColor.g, texColor.b, texColor.a * v_color.a);
```